# Problems while trying to view the HTML documentation for ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

at my work I had to take over a websites for further maintance. It uses ExtJs 2.0.1. Because I've never used this before I have to get in first.
So I downloaded this version from the website and unzipped to the filesystem. Then I canged to the folder that calls 'docs' and clicked on file 'index.html'. After that, the browser(s) started and then showed me a lot of javascript errors.
Following fore different messages do I get (always and always again):

1. "Unmatched tag, expected: `</img>`"
2. "this.el is null". Source: ext-all(-debug).js
3. Unknown entitie. Source: `&nbsp;`
4. "Cannot apply the namespace 'ext' ". Source: `<a ext:cls`

@1. I could fix it by adding the missing tag (search and replace).

My question is, what I have to do for a running documentation? Where are my mistakes in thinking? Btw, apparently I see the same situations in higher versions.

Thanks for any advice.

PS: I also posted this question in the forum of ExtJs, but there is not an answer yet.

Comment: Are you sure ext.js is loaded correctly? In the net tab, does it show any 404 not found files?

Comment: The net tab in firebug does show anything. I think the reason is, I open the files from the filesystem. Do I need a webserver?

Comment: If the doc is local, you probably don't. That would be stupid to put a doc in your product and to ask the user to use a web server to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for Ext JS 2 and 3 don't work from local filesystem. You need to place them into a web server and view from there. Just for your information: the docs for Ext JS 4 now finally also work from local filesystem.

Alternatively you can access the docs online:

- http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/
- http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/

I don't know about 2.0.1 specifically, but there shouldn't be much difference between it and 2.3.0. If you are going to do some larger maintenance you should upgrade to at least 2.3.0 anyway, maybe even 3.x as 2.x isn't supported any more and the upgrade shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I have to stay out until next year with the complete renew of the website. But thanks for you post, you saved my day and evening. I deployed it on a webserver (Bea Weblogic 9.2) and it does work.